# Getting Started with Angular 2

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to run demo project provided bu angular 2 team from [this link](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) 
But I am facing some issue while running it. Can any please guide me to figure out the issue[image: faced issue]

Comment: You need to run the command from demo folder. Please navigate to demo folder and run the install command.

Comment: `cd Demo` then `npm install`
Better to use the [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/). And follow the angular [official documentation](https://cli.angular.io/)

Comment: add detailed code. i.e your directory structure and where package.json is located.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please navigate to `demo` folder and run the `npm install` command.

```
cd demo
npm install
```